# In React.js, how can I prevent re-render on hard refresh?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, render, page-refresh, use-ref

I have a main menu with 4 pages. If I do a hard refresh when I am on any of the pages, React takes me back to the page 1 screen.  I want the user to stay on the same page when hard refresh happens.

Main Menu

1. page 1
2. page 2
3. page 3
4. page 4

I'm thinking useRef would be helpful, though I don't know how to structure the logic.  Ideas are most appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Nothing you store as React state persists page refreshes. The `LocalStorage` Browser API exists to solve this problem.

> The localStorage read-only property of the window interface allows you to access a Storage object for the Document's origin; the stored data is **saved across browser sessions**. [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage)

You could implement something like that in react with a custom hook like [useLocalStorage](https://usehooks.com/useLocalStorage/) that behaves similarly to `useState`, except that it will persists across page-refreshes using LocalStorage.

```
// persists across page loads
const [currentPage, setCurrentPage] = useLocalStorage('page-name')
```

Comment: Thank you!  So not even useRef persists...?

Comment: No, why would it? useRef, like all of react functionality, happens in RAM. While local storage writes to disk. You can learn more about this here; https://www.tutorialspoint.com/difference-between-ram-and-hdd and here https://blog.logrocket.com/localstorage-javascript-complete-guide/ 

If this answer answers your question, please make sure to mark this as a correct answer to follow Stack Oveflow's guidelines.